# React frontend variable is undefined within return

Tags: reactjs

I'm fairly new to React and somewhat confused by why I can't access this variable I assume its a scope issue, do I need to pass this variable to the return in another way?
Exact error is: Line 47:16:  'filteredData' is not defined  no-undef

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/message")
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error("Request failed ${res.status}");
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data.message);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error);
      });
  }, []);
  // Filter the data to get specific values
  // const filteredName = data ? data.filter(item => item.name === 'name') : null;
  // const filteredPrice = data ? data.filter(item => item.price === 'price') : null;
  const FilteredData = ({ data }) => {
    const filteredData =
      data && Array.isArray(data)
        ? data.map((item) => ({
            name: item.name,
            symbol: item.symbol,
            price: item.quote && item.quote.USD && item.quote.USD.price,
          }))
        : [];
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>CoinBoy</h1>
      <p>
        Get the latest data from multiple trackers such as CoinMarketCap, ...
      </p>
      {error && <p>Error: {error.message}</p>}
      {!data ? (
        <p>Fetching Coins...</p>
      ) : (
        filteredData.map((item) => (
          <div key={item.symbol}>
            <h3>{item.name}</h3>
            <p>Symbol: {item.symbol}</p>
            <p>Price: {item.price}</p>
          </div>
        ))
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```